# Determine if two flat indexed array are equal

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

Supposed we have:

```
$arr1 = array("a", "b");
$arr2 = array("a", "b");
```

and arrays are always sorted. Is this true:

```
if ( $arr1 === $arr2 )
{
     echo "condition met";
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply try it and see? You could probably have done it more quickly than asking the question here

Comment: @MarkBaker Right. I did it. But is it _always_ true even for complex multi dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
($arr1 == $arr2); // TRUE when both  have the same key/value pairs.
($arr1 === $arr2); // TRUE when both have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two (and more) arrays with [array_diff()](http://php.net/array_diff) and look for an empty array, in your case.

```
$diff = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
if(empty($diff)) {
    echo "condition met";
}
```